# Typescript generics and keyof

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

I have issues with `keyof` and generics. Have two objects: one argument `Config`, second result `MyFilter`. `MyFilter` should be created with keys of `Config`. Please help:

```
enum Type {
  Boolean,
  Number,
  String,
}

// f.e. { name: Type.String, age: Type.Number }
interface Config {
  [key: string]: Type;
}

// should have the same keys as Config and corresponding types, f.e. { name: "Expecto Patronum!", age: 43 }
type MyFilter<C extends Config> = {
  [Key in keyof C]: C[Key] extends Type.Boolean
    ? boolean
    : C[Key] extends Type.Number
    ? number | null
    : C[Key] extends Type.String
    ? string | null
    : undefined;
};

// C and F should have same keys, but how to create F var and iterate over C to fill F with keyof
function createFilter<C extends Config = Config, F extends MyFilter<C> = MyFilter<C>>(config: C): F {
    const filter = {}

    // DO loop
    switch (config[key]) {
        case Type.Boolean:
            filter[key] = true
        case Type.Number:
            filter[key] = 43
        case Type.String:
            filter[key] = "Expecto Patronum!"
    }
    // END loop

    return filter
}
```

[Playground Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAKgngB2FA3gKClAQgexwG2AEMQAaDKAOUgCNgAnczAZQBd6BLEAc3IF80aAPRCoAMwB0wCaiggiEYAC5YiaW049SUIt2WqkE6hDr0oArqwZiiAY2QBhHCDEduqCgG0A1sDgqAZ3YubgBdFXgkAG40AWFRAIALHDB8ABMoRKIAN2RWROQAhWRfOACdcqcXNx0QDNscenpgAIRnNJCoVjUA7UlpWXlFFQAiAFEADyRbVhwoAAUidmdIAEIR7V19ABYAZnM0bqQoAFk4ADEOfCt6AB4HKGAJqzrK51duAD4oAF4PTE8AGk-FAuFBSjgxFAHOFoUC-KFHs9QGlypFpLgCMQQBRMAB%20KA0PCEEi4qAqBzwuCIp4vVEGaTGUxkgngEwMKAAHzkqXwZIpVJpyNeDIkGhCLKgQU07m54HwfMwmBUYDqwFcIGAaRifBi8WhtQy5ylyVSGSyuSlxXBfl6hLArEyOAA7l05rZmktkMbskQzCQMhwbl6oDhcmYHrNxFd8FBjc6g4kbXBIWgxKqZhxnFAPcQrJdrgx7ki6W9qu4-lUPtpjbSUeUzgWbvdvn9G1dmw5Pp8ABQNcsUgCUKmN6CVOecQWjhbMfxQcXHIigABEAPJQfB4BBkgIJ1i2JN995uHwIwf-cdK2xEALIdESTEkkBKMmXpWuGen6m-Lr0MDAV8rxvO81CMWgGBfN83w-G4v0RP49kAzBr1vUVxR4SCoPHGCGDgn9ximYAZjmRZljZdYyQERdRDGShlw3LdBHHZpWDAegQGnG5YiAA)

Comment: Where does `key` come from in the `createFilter` function?

Comment: @CodyDuong that what I need to get. They `key` is basically are all keys from config. But it should be valid type.

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely understand your question. Is this what you're looking for: https://tsplay.dev/NdYodm? Is there any particular reason F has to be a generic?

Comment: @CodyDuong thank you a lot! If you want you can post an answer. And I will accept as an asnwer.

Comment: You should not have a type parameter `F extends MyFilter<C>`. There is no arbitrary `F`, your function always just returns `MyFilter<C>` and nothing else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not necessary for filter to be a generic. Then using the [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) you can iterate over the object. Then utilize type casting with the `as` operator to assert the type.

```js
function createFilter<C extends Config = Config>(config: C): MyFilter<C> {
    const filter: Record<string, any> = {}

    // DO loop
    for (const key in config) {
      switch (config[key]) {
        case Type.Boolean:
            filter[key] = true
        case Type.Number:
            filter[key] = 43
        case Type.String:
            filter[key] = "Expecto Patronum!"
    }
    }
    // END loop

    return filter as MyFilter<C>
}
```

[TS Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/NdYodm)